# L logL space and compactness

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis

I think that if a sequence of L^1 functions have the integral 
$$
\int f_n \log (f_n)dx
$$
uniformly bounded, then there is a subsequence that converges strongly in $L^1$.

The questions are:

1) Is this correct?

2) Can you give me a good reference for this topic?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) No. Take the sequence of functions $f_n$ on the unit interval defined in the following way: $f_n(x)=1$ (resp., 2) if the $n$-th digit in the dyadic decomposition of $x$ is 1 (resp., 0).

2) What is true is following. Your condition (or rather, uniform boundedness of $\int |f_n|\log^+|f_n|$ implies that the sequence $f_n$ is **uniformly integrable**, which by **Dunford-Pettis theorem** is equivalent to relative compactness of the sequence $f_n$ in the **weak topology** $\sigma(L^1,L^\infty)$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Can you give me a reference?

Comment: For instance, the first chapter of the old book by P.-A. Meyer "Probability and potentials"